# Reading pivot table with c#

Tags: c#, excel, jet

I am trying to read an excel-sheet  containing a pivot table generated by macros with the following connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=path;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;";
```

the problem is that the values doesn't appear in my dataset, only labels of columns and lines, but not necessary values.

Any idea to read a such file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but by changing the provider to `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, data is read correctly.

the fill dataset is slower, i but I got what i'm looking for 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the answer, but maybe Epplus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) could help you.

Comment: Or ty to change the connection property HDR (header) to YES.

Answer (score 0):

This will read and excel table into data table in C#. 'sHeet' is the name of the sheet in Excel and startfromrow is where you want the table read to start from. excelTable is the Data Table where the data will be stored.

```
public void ReadEx(string sHeet, int startfromrow)
       {
          excelTable.Clear();
          string excelFile =  "filepath";
          Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
          Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
          Excel.Worksheet pivotWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[sHeet];
          Excel.Range xlRange = pivotWorkSheet.UsedRange;

          int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
          int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;


          if (excelTable.Columns.Count <= 0)
            {
              excelTable.Columns.Add("Row Labels");
              foreach (string column in lColumns)
              {
                  excelTable.Columns.Add(column);
              }
            }

          object[] exrow = new object[colCount];
          for (int i; startfromrow <= rowCount; row++)
          {
              for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
              {
                  exrow[j-1] = xlRange.Cells[startfromrow , j].Text;
                  Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[startfromrow , j].Text);
              }
              excelTable.Rows.Add(exrow);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some amendment on the answer from user3644719. In his/her answer, there are some typo, like variable not defined in the code.

```
        String sHeet = "Pivot";

        DataTable excelTable = new DataTable();

        excelTable.Clear();
        string excelFile = "C:\\test_pivot.xlsx";
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
        Excel.Worksheet pivotWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[sHeet];
        Excel.Range xlRange = pivotWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        string[] lColumns = new string[2] { "Column1","Column2" };

        if (excelTable.Columns.Count <= 0)
        {
            foreach (string column in lColumns)
            {
                excelTable.Columns.Add(column);
            }

        }

        Object[] exrow = new object[colCount];
        for (int row=1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {  
                exrow[j - 1] = xlRange.Cells[row, j].Text;
                Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[row, j].Text);
            }

            excelTable.Rows.Add(exrow);
            //excelTable.Rows.Add(exrow);
        }

        String str = excelTable.ToString();
    }
```